# finding all points around a point in a cube

Tags: python, geometry, nearest-neighbor

Let's say I have list of points `P0, P1, P2, P3` with coordinates `X,Y,Z`

Then I have a list of points with coordinates `X1, Y1, Z1`

I had to find all points inside a certain radius around `P0`: I did this using python scipy library using `kdtree` and `query_ball_point` function.

But now I'd like to find all points inside a cube. Points (`P0` and `P1`) are not centered in the rectangle.

(Z)height of the rectangle is Z+4. 
(Y)The left side of `P0` is +2 and right side of `P0` is +1. 
To get X we need to calculate the distance between `P0` and `P1`...

Any ideas?

I have good programming knowledge but my math and geometry skills are lacking.

Comment: I'm not being able to understand the question. What does left side of P0 is +2 and right side of P0 is +1 mean? what are P0 and P1? Points inside the cube?

Comment: okay. imagine drawing a rectangle around every point. and every point is centered in the rectangle...  but in my case it is not centered. the left side has 2meters and right side is 1 meter

Comment: Your problem still doesn't make sense to me. So what do you know about P1? Where do P3,P4 go in? If you only know the relative position of P0 it's hard to know anything, also which rectangle is that? The rectangle with Z = 0 of the cube?

Comment: I can draw my problem and post picture later if it helps at anything... I want to solve the problem for the sake of my curiosity and because I want to improve my understanding of geometry. may I contact you personally later today?

Comment: look, if you cant find center of your cube, it means you cant solve the problem. And if you want to understand geometry, why you use scipy library?

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is check all distnace conditions for every point in relation to your rectangle - in all dimensions x,y,z.

Lets say you have center of rectangle with coordinates cx,cy,cz

and you know that distance from X side is dX, from Y side is dY and from Z side is dZ.

the coordinates of your socalled center is cx,cy,cz

you can make loop

```
for point in all_points:
    px,py,pz = point # coordinates of a point which you try to examine

    if abs(cx-point[x]) < dX:
        if abs(cy-point[y]) < dY:
            if abs(cz-point[z]) < dZ:
                print('point is inside so called cube')


#abs(cx-point[x]) equals distance between your center and examined point in x-axis dimension...
#dX is distance between cube side and cx (center of cube in x-axis)
```

**NOTE:**

This example is good for cube with center in the middle. Since your center is not really in the middle, I advice you to find the center and do the above example

**If you cant calculate center of your cube, you cant solve this problem anyway, so you better find the center.**